# Filter Internal/cascading entities using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have below class structure,

```
public partial class Class1 : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class2> Class2s  { get; set; }

}


public partial class Class2 : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Class1")]
    public Guid Class1_Id  { get; set; }
    public virtual Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        Meta = new MetaData();
    }
    public MetaData Meta  { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MetaData
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Modified { get; set; }

    public MetaData()
    {
        Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Active = true;
    }
}
```

Now using EF,

```
var dbContext.Class1
.Include(x=>x.Class2)
where (x=>x.Meta.Active)
```

Now I want to load/filter/get all active class2 entities using above query.

I have tried to apply filter on 
    .Include(x=>x.Class2).Where(y=>y.Meta.Active)

but it apply only on Class1. I want to filter all active class2 entities.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: .Include(x=>x.Class2) (I think you means Class2s) will return an IQueryable<Class1>. so in your where call, you have to navigate to class 2 again .Include(x=>x.Class2s).Where(x=>x.Class2s.Any(y=>y.Meta.Active))

Comment: No that is not working. It will not filter class2

Answer (score 0):

To filter navigation property collection you can use method [Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx). It looks like this:

```
context.Entry(blog) 
    .Collection(b => b.Posts) 
    .Query() 
    .Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("entity-framework") 
    .Load();
```

Or you can do the following:

```
dbContext.Class1
    .Select(s => new {class1 = s, navigationProps = s.Class2s.Where(w => w.Meta.Active)})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => s.class1);
```

Comment: Second Query is working. but i don't want to use anonymous object. Because I have very big list of include statements its about 50 child entities.